# How to get item from the Algolia records into template

Tags: mustache, algolia, hugo, instantsearch.js

Hi I'm trying to create template for hits widget.

For the example here is my item record structure

```
categories  [xxx]
date    1445165400
description "blah blah blah"
image   "/image/content/2015/10/xxx.jpg"
lastmod 1519151656
objectID    "xxx"
permalink   "http://example.com/xxx/"
publishdate "2015-10-18T10:50:00Z"
relpermalink    "/xxx/"
section "blog"
summary "blah blah blah"
tags    […]
title   "Lorem Ipsum"
type    "blog"
url "/xxx/"
weight  0
```

I'm using instantsearch.js and mustache.js for templating.

Here is my hits template

```
<script type="text/html" id="hit-template">
  <div class="hit">
    <div class="hit-image">
      <img src="{{ "{{image}}" }}">
    </div>
    <div class="hit-content">      
      <a class="hit-url" href="{{url}}">
      <h2 class="hit-name">{{ "{{title}}" }}</h2>
      </a>
      <p class="hit-description">{{ "{{{_highlightResult.summary.value}}}" }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>  
</script>
```

I'm using Hugo so I have to wrap the musctahe with brackets and double quotes

The title and description rendered as it should be, but not with the image and the url.

here is the result

```
<div class="ais-hits--item">
  <div class="hit">
    <div class="hit-image">
      <img src="%7b%7bimage%7d%7d" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="hit-content">      
      <a class="hit-url" href="%7b%7burl%7d%7d">
      <h2 class="hit-name">My Post Title</h2>
      </a>
      <p class="hit-description">lorem blah blah blah <em>highlihted keyword</em> <em>highlihted keyword</em> blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

I wonder how to get the image and url value?

## UPDATE

I expect the mustache template render the value as it should be, from the example above mustache failed to render the value inside `href` and `src`, but after some trial I found that there is no recollection on HTML attributes in Mustache templating, so I assume there was conflict between Mustache and Hugo which makes Mustache template failed render the value.

I finaly realize in Hugo (specialy inside href and src atributes case) I have to wrap the HTML tag and mustache in weird way than usualy.

In case someone have the same experience (using Hugo and Mustache) here's the workaround

```
{{ safeHTML "<a href=\"{{permalink}}\">" }}
```

Cheers

Comment: It seems that every attribute from Algolia shown inside a tag is working (title, description), but when inside an html attribute (image) it's not working. Can you try to display the image an html tag rather than inside an attribute just to confirm this is the issue? Then if that's the issue try to see how with Hugo templating language you can do this attribute properly.

Comment: I already check the value from image and url is fine I found that there is conflict between Hugo and Muctache template, since they use the same curly braces.

Comment: @wo  the case is solved, thank  you